# How do I change my keyboard type to JIS in terminal?

Tags: keyboard, japanese

I have a JIS type keyboard but osx is recognizing it as ANSI

Before you answer
There is no "change keyboard type" button in keyboard settings

there is no file named com.apple.keyboardtype.plist

I have tried to manually open the keyboard setup wizard but when I click it nothing happens

Comment: Do you have this problem Only in Terminal, not in other apps too?

Comment: Please give specific example of how it is "recognized as ANSI".  What character is produced when you press the key at the top left corner?

Comment: No, Im asking how to change the keyboard type to JIS via terminal command line

Comment: Download karabiner elements and you can change the keyboard setting for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```bsh
 /System/Library/CoreServices/KeyboardSetupAssistant.app/Contents/MacOS/KeyboardSetupAssistant
```

Works for my Bluetooth device.

I'm also currently trying to find a way to do it through the Terminal (to create a `launctl` so I don't have to run it every time it goes to sleep) without any luck so far. I will update this post once I find a way.